# Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-sources

Whenever I am  updating my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Desktop, the following error occurs in terminal:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release 
   Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file
   (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix this?

`cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list` gives me this

```
1 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted
2
3 # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
4 # newer versions of the distribution.
5 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
6 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
7
8 ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
9 ## distribution.
10 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
11 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
12
13 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
14 ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
15 ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
16 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
17 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
18 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
19 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
20
21 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
22 ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
23 ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
24 ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
25 ## security team.
26 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
27 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
28 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
29 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
30
31 ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
32 ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
33 ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
34 ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
35 ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
36 deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
37 deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
38
39 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
40 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
41 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
42 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
43 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
44 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
45
46 ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
47 ## 'partner' repository.
48 ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
49 ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
50 deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
51 deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
52
53 ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
54 ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
55 deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
56 deb http://archive.canonical.com trusty partner
57 # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com trusty partner
58 deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: You need to add the content of the list to the question, `cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Try to comment out line 56, hope it helps.

Comment: @mikewhatever commented.  Same error.

Comment: Well, that list look ok, other then the lines 56 and 57, which are malformed and shouldn't be there at all.